# How do I animate an image to move on command?

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a code here which is to make this image move to the left if the left arrow key is pressed, however it does not seem to be doing much of anything

```
   let posx = 0;
document.getElementById("ship").addEventListener("ArrowLeft", moveLeft);
function moveLeft(){
    if (event.code == "ArrowLeft"){
        posx -= 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `posx` somewhere else in your code? Also, you should add an `event` parameter to `moveLeft` instead of using a global `event` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe that "ArrowLeft" is an event for which the ship element can listen.  Consider using the "keydown" event instead

```js
var posX = 100;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var notPressedElement = document.getElementById("notPressed");
  var pressedElement = document.getElementById("Pressed");
  var keyElement = document.getElementById("keyName");
  notPressedElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
  pressedElement.style.visibility = "visible";
  keyElement.innerText = event.key;

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      posX -= 2;
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      posX += 2;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  var posXElement = document.getElementById("posXValue");
  posXElement.innerText = posX.toString();
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  var notPressedElement = document.getElementById("notPressed");
  var pressedElement = document.getElementById("Pressed");
  var keyElement = document.getElementById("keyName");
  notPressedElement.style.visibility = "visible";
  pressedElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
  keyElement.innerText = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="demoDiv">
  <div id="notPressed" style="visibility: visible;">
    <h3>Key Pressed: None</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="Pressed" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <h3>Key Pressed: <span id="keyName"></span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>PosX = <span id="posXValue">100</span></h3>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple canvas example.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand, PassGen, dig; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
const stage = I('stage'), ctx = stage.getContext('2d'), see = M('img');
let seeX = 0, seeY = 0, pW = innerWidth-20, pH = innerHeight-20;
function can(){
  let w = innerWidth-20, h = innerHeight-20;
  seeX += (w-pW); seeY += (h-pH); pW = stage.width = w; pH = stage.height = h; 
  if(seeX < 1)seeX = 0;
  if(seeY < 1)seeY = 0;
  ctx.drawImage(see, seeX, seeY);
}
function clear(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height);
}
can();
see.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
see.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvKY9.png?s=48&g=1';
onresize = can;
onkeydown = function(e){
  let n;
  switch(e.key){
    case 'ArrowUp':  
      if(seeY > 9){
        seeY -= 10;
      }
      else{
        seeY = 0;
      }
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      n = stage.width-see.width;
      if(seeX < n-9){
        seeX += 10; 
      }
      else{
        seeX = n;
      }
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      n = stage.height-see.height;
      if(seeY < n-9){
        seeY += 10;
      }
      else{
        seeY = n;
      }
      break;
    case 'ArrowLeft':;
      if(seeX > 9){
        seeX -= 10; 
      }
      else{
        seeX = 0;
      }
      break;  
  }
  clear(); ctx.drawImage(see, seeX, seeY);
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
#stage{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <canvas id='stage'></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```